# sender parameter is null in ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, selectedindexchanged

I have a WinForm application with a ListBox containing few list items. In the InitializeComponent(), The ListBox has a **listBoxSelectedIndexChanged** event attached.

By default, the first item is selected and SelectedIndexChanged event gets triggered but **sender** parameter is null, in the listBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e).

Only after I click on an item in the ListBox, the **sender** parameter holds some value.

Any possible solutions so that **sender** parameter holds some value if the ListBox has first item preselected?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I would guess that you are calling the event in code and witha null sender

Comment: The event is raised if you set the DataSource or the `SelectedIndex` value *manually*, but the Control should not be `null`, since it can raise events. -- Show your code.